# Intercept Apollo/GraphQL requests on ReactNative with PollyJS

Tags: react-native, apollo-client, detox, pollyjs

We have a React Native App using Apollo, now we are integrating Detox for e2e tests. We need to provide mocking responses to the test for making them feasible, so we are trying to integrate PollyJS for recording the requests.

As far as I know ApolloClient uses `fetch` to make the http request, so we are trying to use the `FetchAdapter` in PollyJS to record the requests.

We are expecting to have records from the Apollo client, but only calling fetch actually triggers Polly to record a request.

Answer (score 1):

As the mantainers says on the issue tracker on their [Github], Polly instance should be initialized before fetch is modified to keep track of the original `fetch` call.